# React/Preact .map an icon that when clicked runs a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

So I've been given vague instruction on a school project:

> .map an icon that when clicked, runs a function that puts the key of
>   the .map in as the argument which then grabs the image and audio

I haven't been given any base code to work with. I'm just not sure where to start. Any help would be appreciated on using .map

Answer (score 2):

This is really vague. Are you sure your professor didn't have any additional instructions? Does your professor want this as an element on a webpage or a standalone icon/app/exe that runs on the desktop?

So `map` is a method on the Array class. It creates a new array from the results of performing a function (callback) on every element of the initial array. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
//example
const arrayOfNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
// returns array of each element multiplied by 2
arrayOfNumbers.map(num => num*2)
// = [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

It sounds like you have some sort of mapping (object/hash) that has a key and points to the image/audio source (url). It looks like you would want some image/icon that when click, fires off an event hander whose callback would be to take the keys from this object and key into the object using map to grab your files sources. Then you can display it or something on the DOM?

But it definitely sounds like you should've received additional information to solve this problem.

Comment: This helps quite a bit, I asked the professor and he said there was no additional instructions needed... Would there be a way I could reach out to you to dissect this a little bit further?

Comment: @ecorp sure. I took a look at Win solution and its more or less how you would want to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an actual example that you can dig around.

1. We start off by creating a library of records. This library is just an array of items (in the form of objects) that we want to access. Each object within the array has an id (that we will use to access records and store an active record id), title, image url and a sound file url.
2. We create a parent component that contains simple logic to set an active record id. We don't actually use this function within the parent components render method but pass it down to our `<Record/>` component to use.
3. We render the libary in the method but we just map the library id's into a new array before mapping the `<Record/>` component because your assignment criteria is to return an image and a sound by mapping an id.
4. We create a simple component that renders a record and uses the set prop that we have passed down from the parent component to set the active record id. Since we need to locate the record first we use a `find` to filter down the `Library` array, so that we have a single object that we can use to display the title.

The handle click method was created to run the set prop function as we don't want to just do `onClick={() => this.props.set(this.props.id)}` in the render method because it'll create a new function every time the component is re-rendered. (This is an optimisation)

5. Lastly but not least, the `<ActiveRecord/>` presentation component is similar to the above but this finds a record based on the active record id that has been passed down. This component renders the image and sound.

Have a play around! This code could be shortened but we really want to hit the assessment criteria where we need to map id's which makes the `<Record/>` component a little more complicated (by not passing down the whole record down and having to use `.find`)

Let me know if you need more information.

Notes: We are not using class transform properties.

```js
/**
 * Static const that keeps a list of records
 */
const Library = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Service Bell',
    sound: 'http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=2218&type=mp3',
    image: 'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/401039903298-0-1/s-l1000.jpg',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Dog',
    sound: 'http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=2215&type=mp3',
    image: 'https://lovinlife.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Dog.jpg',
  }
]

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    /**
     * State for storing selected record id
     */
    this.state = {
      activeRecordId: null,
    };

    this.setActiveRecord = this.setActiveRecord.bind(this);
  };

  /**
   * Sets active record
   * @param id {string}
   */
  setActiveRecord(id) {
    this.setState({
      activeRecordId: id,
    });
  };

  /**
   * Render
   */
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h5>Library</h5>
        {Library.map(record => record.id).map(recordId => <Record recordId={recordId} set={this.setActiveRecord} />)}
        {this.state.activeRecordId && <ActiveRecord activeRecordId={this.state.activeRecordId}/>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

/**
 * Displays a record
 */
class Record extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // binds handle click so that you can access
    // props within the function
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  };

  /**
   * Call parent prop that sets the active record id back
   * in the parent container
   */
  handleClick() {
    this.props.set(this.props.recordId);
  };

  /**
   * Render record based on props
   */
  render() {
    const record = Library.find(record => record.id === this.props.recordId);
    return (
      <div>
        {record.title}
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>View</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

/**
 * Displays an active record
 */
function ActiveRecord({ activeRecordId }) {
  const activeRecord = Library.find(record => record.id === activeRecordId);
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Active Record</h3>
      <img width="100" src={activeRecord.image} />
      <audio controls>
        <source src={activeRecord.sound} type="audio/mp3" />
      </audio>
    </div>
  )
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I appreciate it. I will let you know if you have any questions.